# What happens with vulgar user names?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Just came across [this new user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/110930/bitch) after their name popped up in the review queue. Someone already made a point to them about their user name [on this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212438/how-do-i-kick-someone-from-my-pe-server/217233#217233), but what actually happens in this situation?

Comment: Your link, "on this answer", may be to an incorrect answer, as there is no comment about usernames... May be worth double checking the link.

Comment: @Greenonline most likely the answer was removed already or the username was reverted as LessPop talks about in the answer below since asking this

Comment: @green the answer in question was deleted. Quite apart from the username issue, it simply did not answer the question. It's still visible to 10k users.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As with most issues, just flag it for moderator attention, and/or, if you feel comfortable, leave a comment on their post asking them to change it.

Mods can and will reset the username to a default (UserXXXXX or whatever).

Comment: which is what I did

Comment: Can you flag a user from their profile? There's a new user with a similarly inappropriate name [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122220/shitballs), and their only answer has already been deleted.